# removing specific axis ticks in geom_raster in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the code below, because `expand=c(0,0)` is used, some axis ticks overlap. I want to delete `0.5` in the y-axis of the bottom row, and `1.00` in the x-axis of the first two columns (i.e., total three numbers).

In addition, although `expand=c(0,0)` is used, there are still some gray region. I want to eliminate it completely. In fact, the tick location is inaccurate (e.g., the result for (x=0,y=0) is not at (x=0,y=0)).

```
x.i <- seq(0,1,length=30)
z.i <- c(0.1,0.5,0.9)
y.i <- seq(0,0.5,length=30)
b.i <- c(10,100)


out <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(x.i)){
  x <- x.i[i]
for(k in 1:length(z.i)){
  z <- z.i[k]
for(l in 1:length(y.i)){
  y   <- y.i[l]
for(m in 1:length(b.i)){
    b <- b.i[m]

   cc <- rbinom(1,3,0.5)

out <- rbind(out,c(x,z,y,b,cc))
}}}}

colnames(out) <- c("x","z","y","b","qd")
out <- as.data.frame(out)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(out,aes(x,y))+geom_raster(aes(fill=factor(qd)))+facet_grid(b~z)+
xlab("x")+ylab("y")+ scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,1), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,0.5), expand = c(0, 0)) +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkgoldenrod2","tomato3","yellow","darkgreen"),name="case")
```

[image: myplot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `geom_rect` to eliminate the grey area.

```
ggplot(out,aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = x, 
                xmax = x + 0.03448276, 
                ymin = y, 
                ymax = y + 0.01724138, 
                fill = factor(qd))) +
  facet_grid(b~z)+
  xlab("x") + ylab("y") + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1 + 0.03448276), 
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.5 + 0.01724138), 
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkgoldenrod2","tomato3","yellow","darkgreen"),name="case")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is very good. Could you also delete "1.00" in the x-axis for the first two columns?

Comment: I don't think it is currently supported, as it would require a different scale per facet, e.g. see [this feature request](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1613).

Comment: Thank you. I guess in this kind of situation, removing "1.00" from all columns may be an acceptable solution for now.

Comment: Another way to deal with your overlapping axis labels is to increase the spacing between panels, using `theme(panel.spacing = unit(5,"mm"))`. You can also just specify the spacing in the x direction.